# Is it possible for `dotnet publish` skip code analysis

Tags: .net, editorconfig

I have as a dependency autogenerated project and don't want to fix all code styles.
I've found this [recommendations](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23591#issuecomment-507802134) but it doesn't work for me.
`dotnet publish "MySolytion.csproj" /p:RunAnalyzers=False -c Release` doesn't work

**Update**:
Autogenerated code lay in the separate project and it is dependency of main project.
There are flags `<RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>false</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis> <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>` and Visual Studio build is without issues. But there are errors while building from dockerfile.

**Update2:**
it was reproducing on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`, but for `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` works well

Comment: If you have control over the code generation - try adding  `// <auto-generated />` comment to the top of the code files.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for the answer, it looks like solution for me